# Price filter and sorting is not working in Products with custom options Magento

Tags: magento, filter, price

I am magento with porto theme. Sort by price and price filter is not working perfectly only with some products with same attribute set.

This attribute set has products with custom options which has different price rates.

check the image for detail view:

[Please check screenshot](http://prntscr.com/e0xrx4)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I already posted in magento stack exchange.